# MySQL-Making query usingPHP

Tags: php, mysql

I have some basic query and I want to expand it if some other parameter is given. I hope you will understand what I'm trying when you see code.

```
$proizvodjac=$_GET["p_proizvodjac"];
$query="SELECT v.proizvodjac,v.naziv,v.godina_proizvodnje,
               v.cijena, v.slika, v.tip, v.broj_vrata, 
               v.gorivo, v.automatik, p.naziv_poslovnice
        FROM vozilo v
        LEFT JOIN poslovnica p ON poslovnica_id=idposlovnica";

if($proizvodjac!="NULL"){
    $query=$query."WHERE v.proizvodjac=\"$proizvodjac\"";
}
```

I'm using this query for search in database. 
When `$proizvodjac=="NULL"` everything works fine cause it does not enter in if statment, but when `$proizvodjac!="NULL"`, I got below error

```
"You have an error in your SQL syntax; 
 check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the 
 right syntax to use near 'v.proizvodjac="Skoda"' at line 4"
```

Please help whats wrong is with my code?Thx
I get $proizvodjac from this form

```
<select name="p_proizvodjac">
                    <option value="NULL"></option>
                    <option value="Audi">Audi</option>
                    <option value="Skoda">Skoda</option>
                    <option value="Renault">Renault</option>
                    <option value="HYUNDAI">HYUNDAI</option>
                    <option value="VW">VW</option>
                    <option value="Fiat">Fiat</option>
                    <option value="Opel">Opel </option>
                </select>
```

Comment: write `$query = $query." WHERE v.proizvodjac= $proizvodjac";`. Is $proizvodjac a string ?

Comment: If it's a string write `$query = $query." WHERE v.proizvodjac= '$proizvodjac'";`

Comment: Why are you concatenating a query together instead of using [PreparedStatements](http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepared-statements.php)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you need to add a space to the query part in the if statement:

```
$proizvodjac=$_GET["p_proizvodjac"];
        $query="SELECT v.proizvodjac,v.naziv,v.godina_proizvodnje, 
v.cijena, v.slika, v.tip, v.broj_vrata, v.gorivo, v.automatik, p.naziv_poslovnice
        FROM vozilo v
        LEFT JOIN poslovnica p
        ON poslovnica_id=idposlovnica";
        if($proizvodjac!="NULL"){
            $query=$query." WHERE v.proizvodjac=\"$proizvodjac\"";
        }
```

otherwise the WHERE is directly connected to the first part, which results in the error.

Comment: When i write question, i noticed it, but same error. NULL is also string, and $proizvodjac is a string, name of car. VW, Audi,Skoda etc.

Comment: I tride this again, and its work...thx for help to everyone ;)

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
if($proizvodjac != null) { // "null" is a string, which is not null
    $query .= " WHERE v.proizvodjac=\"$proizvodjac\""; // add a space in your string and use .= to concatenate
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this; where condition parameter using single quotes

```
if($proizvodjac != null) {
    $query = $query . " WHERE v.proizvodjac='$proizvodjac'";
}
```